# Deleted Dataset from Web UI but no change in Billing Reports

Tags: google-bigquery

I deleted few BigQuery datasets from BigQuery Web UI. Those datasets had tables containing about 400 TB in Long Term Storage. Surprisingly, even after 48 hrs of the deletion operation, I am not seeing any drop in Long Term Storage charges graph/data in billing reports. I did not notice such delay when deleting just tables. Is there a time delay by when Dataset deletion changes are reflected in billing?

Comment: Do you have Billing Export to BigQuery enabled ? Because if yes, you can add labels to your data set and break down the cost per dataset and check the current charges. Also, you can check all your current datasets in you project using `bq ls --all`, so you can check which datasets are within your project. Would this help you?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes: This is helpful. I will try it out. We are not using dataset labels yet.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a delay of upto 48hrs or so. Eventually, billing reports are showing the drop in storage.